# My proof of ratio lemma for sequences tending to inf.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My proof of $(b_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers. Support there exists $z\gt 1$ s.t. $b_{n+1}/b_n\ge z\forall n$ .Show $(b_n)\rightarrow \infty$

---

If $l\gt 1$ s.t. $b_{n+1}/b_n\ge z\forall n$ then $b_{n+1}/b_n\ge z\gt1$. So $b_{n+1}\ge zb_n\gt b_n\implies b_{n+1}\gt b_n\forall n$. Since this is a definition of a strictly increasing sequence we get that $(b_n)\rightarrow \infty$.

---

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: $b_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ is strictly increasing...

Comment: A sequence can be strictly increasing without tending to infinity. What you need to show is that the sequences is not bounded above by any real number.

Comment: Can I say that if $b_{n+1}/b_n=z\gt 1$ then $z^n=(1+(z-1))^n\gt1+n(z-1)\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: By induction $b_n \geq b_1 z^{n-1}$. Hence $b_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. There are strictly increasing sequences that do not converge to $+\infty$. An example of such a sequence is $-1/n \nearrow 0$.

One way to do this properly is to note that for all $n \geq 1$

$$b_{n} \geq zb_{n-1} \geq z^2 b_{n-2} \geq \dots \geq z^{n-1} b_1$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} z^{n-1} b_1 = + \infty$ (since $z > 1$), it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = + \infty$ by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this proof, note that if $b_n$ has an upper bound then it must converge. This would mean that $b_{n+1}$  would converge to the same limit. So the limit of the ratio $\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ would be one. This means that for all $\epsilon >0$, there is some $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1|<\epsilon$. If we pick $\epsilon = z-1$ this would mean that there is an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1|<z-1$. This would imply that for all $n>N$, $\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}